# UISegmentedControl selected segment changed

Tags: nsstring, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl and I want to change the selected segment programmatically by a value on another view controller. I attempted to use an NSString but it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use NSUserDefaults.

save your string in NSUserDefaults in another view controller like

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"first" forKey:@"uniquekey"];
```

then make if condition in a viewcontroller which has UISegmentedcontroll like

first get nsstring from nsuserdefaults like

```
NSString *getstr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uniquekey"];
```

then make if condition

```
if([getstr isEqualToString:@"first"]
{
    segment first
}
else
{
    segment second
}
```